# How do I append to an array of type object?

Tags: c#

So i have this `object output`

```cs
object output = new[] { "string1", "string2", "string3" };
```

but later down the line i want to append `"string4"` to it.
So i tried:

```cs
output.Add("string4");
```

but I'm getting a `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add'`
so i tried the following:

```cs
((Array) output).Add("string4"); // also does not contain a definition for 'Add'
((List<string>) output).Add("string4"); // which gets rid of the red lines, but will this work with the initial contents of output?
```

I am not able to change the initialization. So I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: arrays are fixed size, use a list instead - as per Nigel answer

Comment: `object output = new[] { "string1", "string2", "string3" };` **does not** mean "`output` is an array of these objects". It means "`output` is an object, which specfically is this array". Because the fact that it's an array isn't declared in the variable type, array methods are not available - the *static* type does not provide them. That said, C# arrays don't have an `.Add` method, and can't be resized. You were presumably thinking of some other sequence type, such as `List<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
List<string> output = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3" };
output.Add("string4");
```

Comment: Yes, i could, but i did indicate that I am not able to change the initialization. However, I guess i can convert this list with `ToArray()` afterwards.

Comment: @AJGodinez that does not have the quite same effect as appending to the array. If you really want to append to an array that is not possible